# Firebug v2.0.1 breaking on old breakpoints

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firebug, breakpoints

I've added and removed breakpoints, but Firebug still stops at those old breakpoints on subsequent page refreshes.

I've tried fixes for this very same problem with older releases (i.e. *Reset All Firebug options* and deleting the breakpoints.json), but they're not working.

Any ideas how to get around this issue without having to wait for the release fixing it?

Comment: Even restarted the browser?

Comment: Why don't you tell the Firebug developers about it by [filing an issue](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list) (if there isn't one filed already)?

Comment: @nmaier while that may be a solution to the problem it the long run, I'm currently looking for a workaround at the moment. It'll take more time than I can afford to wait for an update to get pushed out.

Comment: @RahilWazir you're right, most of the time a browser restart seems to get rid of it (although there have been occasions where it didn't for some reason). However, restarting the browser every time I change or remove a breakpoint is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebug Working Group is working on fixing this problem in [issue 7301](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=7301). The issue is currently missing a reproducible test case. So any tips that help to fix this problem or a simple test case should be posted there.

You and nmaier already named the workarounds known so far, which are Firebug menu > *Options* > *Reset All Firebug Options* or deleting the breakpoints.json file manually from the profile folder followed by a browser restart.